# can JAXB parse "" to double?

Tags: jaxb

I am getting this error when unmarshalling an xml

> java.lang.NumberFormatException:
> at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDouble(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:232)

while checking on the xml and my classes for double values, I've found one of the elements of the xml that has a null value for its double attribute (I know it is double because the others of the same element have a double attribute)

```
<data num = "">...</data>
```

data class

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
...
@XmlAttribute(name = "num")
private double num;
//private Double num; //same problem as above
...}
```

can the num attribute be parsed to double if it was null? or is it fine?

Comment: you should provide more details about the class that you are unmarshalling. Anyway, may be declaring the field attribute as a `Double` object instead of a `double` may help

Comment: same problem, for now I had read it as a String and would parse it later. but if there is a way to check before it parse it in the jaxb classes not through DataTypeConverterImp